# How do I disable the afterimages on p5.js?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

When I draw a shape and it is moved or scaled the background turns grey. This can be any shape, ellipse, line, rectangle, etc. Here is an [example](https://gyazo.com/078240d3cfbc40471030a218a03c8915) of it.

I tried changing the stroke weight and the fill arguments but that didn't affect it.

Here is the code needed to reproduce it:

```
var bodys = [];

var zoom = 1.00;
var zMin = 0.05;
var zMax = 9.00;
var sensativity = 0.005;
let zoomMultiplier = 50000000;

function mouseWheel(event) {
  zoom += sensativity * -event.delta;
  zoom = constrain(zoom, zMin, zMax);
  return false;
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  //declaring objects[], replacing these with normal ellipses works 
  //if you're trying to reproduce it.
  background(0);
}

function draw() {
  background(0, 20);
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  scale(zoom / zoomMultiplier);

  strokeWeight(500000)
  line(bodys[0].pos.x, bodys[0].pos.y, bodys[1].pos.x, bodys[1].pos.y)

  //...

  for (let bodys of bodys) {
    bodys.show()
  }
}
```

The show function looks like this:

```
show() {
  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(2);
  fill(255, 100);
  ellipse(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.r * 2);
}
```

Comment: Please post the code; I prefer not to sign up for some app.

Comment: Any shape, there's no weird thing added:
stroke(255);strokeWeight(2);
    fill(255, 100);
ellipse(x, y, radius)

for the line I simply did the line() function. If you are talking about the scaling this is it:
var zoom = 1.00;
var zoomMultiplier = 50000000;

draw() {
    scale(zoom / (zoomMultiplier));
}

I only need to know how to get rid of the afterimage it leaves after moving.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how make the comment look more organized.

Comment: You have to add the code in the question. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.**"*

Comment: Copy/paste the code between two sets of graves, ie \```...\```

Comment: Make sure the first line in draw() is a background() call.

Comment: "Sorry I don't know how make the comment look more organized"  because you shouldn't put your code in the comments. You should edit your question and put your code there, properly formatted

Comment: I added the code, although all that you need to reproduce it is to move a shape across a black background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
background(0, 20);
```

This line uses the `background(gray, [a])` overload*, where `a` is "alpha", meaning the opacity/transparency "Number: opacity of the background relative to current color range (default is 0-255)" ([p5 Reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/background:%7E:text=edit-,Syntax,-background(color))).

This is putting a black that's ~92% transparent, so it's not going to completely fill in an area with black until after several frames where the transparency multiplied approaches 0%.

Change the line to

```js
background(0);
```

to get rid of the after-image effect.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, could you please check it as the answer?